# How to make a table responsive for mobile devices and place some columns bellow the others

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html-table, responsive

My name is David, I am a beginner and I have some difficulties finding a solution to my problem:

I have a page with a table, on a WordPress site. **The table is too big for small devices**, such as mobile phones, and I would like to go **from 4 columns to 2 columns** for these devices. What I would like the browser to do is to "cut" the last two columns and place them just below of the first two, because the first and the third column and the second and the forth columns contain the same information.

This would be a simplifier version of the html code:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Artículo</th>
        <th>Descripción</th>
        <th>Artículo</th>
        <th>Descripción</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Image 1</td>
        <td>International Edition ...</td>
        <td>Image 2</td>
        <td>Green Box</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Image 3</td>
        <td>Blue Box ...</td>
        <td>Image 4</td>
        <td>Red Box ...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Image 5</td>
        <td>Absurd Box ...</td>
        <td>Image 6</td>
        <td>The Bigger, Blacker Box ...</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I have thought that it may be possible to tackle this with **CSS**, but all the information I have found on the internet does not match exactly this problem.

Do you know how this could be done?

**Thank you very much!!!!**

Comment: Have you tried implementing 'media queries'?

Comment: Don't use tables for this. Tables are meant for data driven content. You should look into using CSS `grid` and `media queries` for this.

Comment: Rob and Disinfor!! Thank you very much for your support!! :) I did not know about "grid" and "media queries" before. I will work on it and report on the results.